# Client side validation gem not working after changed the value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, client-side-validation

I am using an input field User Name

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="">
```

and using validation using client_side_validation v3.2.6 gem to validate require.

When I change the value of this field using jquery:

```
$('#user_name').val('test');
```

And the value of User Name field change successfully.

But when I submit the form, there show an error 'user name required' when there is already a value 'test'.

If I change the value of user_name using keyboard, it works fine.

Another things I found that if I changed the value of user_name field using keyboard and focusout after changed the value using jquery, it works fine.